# Mechanize and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mechanize

Has someone managed to use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) with Google App Engine application?

Comment: The only information I've been able to find on it is [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275980/import-mechanize-module-to-python-script). Looks like it shouldn't be too difficult, but'll require some hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though you need to either alter the mechanize.py file or do what most people do, which is download an already altered and fixed version of it.
Unsure if this still works, as it’s from 2010.

Below is an altered and fixed version of mechanize for google app engine.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/gaemechanize2/downloads

** This is the code from the project gaemechanize. It gets mechanize working on Google App Engine. It is based on mechanize 0.1.11 and includes clientform.

I'm not sure why it wasn't uploaded to the original gaemechanize project, if there any issues with releasing it this way let me know and I'm take it down.**