# GAE-mechanize sourcecode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mechanize

i saw a project that made mechanize compatible to google app engine. But I couldn't find the sourcecode to it

It would be very nice if someone can give me the source of it, because I most likely need this in the app I'm creating currently.

Answer (score 1):

See [Mechanize and Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389893/mechanize-and-google-app-engine)

I got this by googling [mechanize google app engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=mechanize+google+app+engine).