# Using CookieJar in Python to log in to a website from "Google App Engine". What's wrong here?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, cookiejar

I've been trying to find a python code that would log in to my mail box on yahoo.com from ["Google App Engine"](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)
.
[Here (click here to see that page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914275/googles-app-engine-python-how-to-get-parameters-from-a-log-in-pages) I was given this code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

url = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?"
form_data = {'login' : 'my-login-here', 'passwd' : 'my-password-here'}

jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
form_data = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
# data returned from this pages contains redirection
resp = opener.open(url, form_data)
# yahoo redirects to http://my.yahoo.com, so lets go there instead
resp = opener.open('http://mail.yahoo.com')
print resp.read()
```

The author of this script looked into HTML script of [yahoo log-in form](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym)
and came up with this script.

That log-in form contains two fields, one for users' Yahoo! ID and another one is for users' password. Here is how HTML code of that page for both of those fields looks like:

User ID field:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="96" class="yreg_ipt" size="17" value="" id="username" name="login">
```

Password field:

```
<input type="password" maxlength="64" class="yreg_ipt" size="17" value="" id="passwd" name="passwd">
```

However, when I uploaded this code to Google App Engine I discovered that this log-in form keeps coming back to me, which, I assume, means that logging-in process didn't succeed. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You send MD5 hash and not plain password. Also you'd have to play along with all kinds of CSRF protections etc. that they're implementing. Look:

```
            <input type="hidden" name=".tries" value="1"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".src" value="ym"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".md5" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".hash" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".js" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".last" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="promo" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".intl" value="us"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".bypass" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".partner" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".u" value="bd5tdpd5rf2pg"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".v" value="0"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".challenge" value="5qUiIPGVFzRZ2BHhvtdGXoehfiOj"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".yplus" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".emailCode" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="pkg" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="stepid" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".ev" value=""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="hasMsgr" value="0"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".chkP" value="Y"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".done" value="http://mail.yahoo.com"> 
            <input type="hidden" name=".pd" value="ym_ver=0&c=&ivt=&sg=">
```

Launch Wireshark and play with it. Good luck :)

However if you intend to use it w/ App Engine keep in my mind that using Google IP will almost surely result w/ Captcha challenge. Also Yahoo might block your `User-Agent` that is being set permanently by Google.

Comment: Thank You, deno, for this input. Honestly speaking, I am quite overwhelmed by Your answer - I didn't really know that so many things would be involved, many of which I have never heard before. I have already downloaded the Wireshark and am now trying to study it. Can You, please, teach me (or give me a resource that would teach me) how to transform my plain password into MD5 hash? Also, these lines of code that You have provided here, can I just insert them into my code? If yes, where in my code do I insert them? Thank You once again.

Comment: If you you're using Python look into hashlib documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html). What you'd want to do is:
1. Simulate normal login and save login page that you get
2. Save POST&GET headers w/ wireshark
3. Compare login page w/ those headers and see what fields you need to include w/ your request.
That should do. 

You see usually login pages are just login+password as your friend suggested. However that isn't very secure hence all this additional data.

Please note, however, that if all you want is to read e-mail than it might be simpler to set up HTTP←→IMAP proxy.

Comment: @ deno: Hello, deno!!! Thank You very much for that link on hashlib, it was very helpful. Deno, please tell me what You mean by "simulating normal login". Do You mean that I just have to log in to that page (by filling out ID and Password fields in that form) and then save the HTML code of the page that I get to after clicking "Enter"?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Do just that while Wireshark's running.