# How to transform phrases and words into MD5 hash?

Tags: hash, passwords, md5, endianness

Can anyone, please, explain to me how to transform a phrase like "I want to buy  some milk" into MD5? I read Wikipedia article on MD5, but the explanation given there is beyond my comprehension:

> "MD5 processes a variable-length
>   message into a fixed-length output of
>   128 bits. The input message is broken
>   up into chunks of 512-bit blocks
>   (sixteen 32-bit little endian
>   integers)"

"sixteen 32-bit little endian integers" is already hard for me. I checked the Wiki article on little endians and didn't understand a bit.

However, the examples of some phrases and their MD5 hashes in that Wiki article are very nice:

> MD5("The quick brown fox jumps over
>   the lazy dog")    =
>   9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
>
> MD5("The quick brown fox jumps over
>   the lazy dog.")    =
>   e4d909c290d0fb1ca068ffaddf22cbd0

Can anyone, please, explain to me how this MD5 algorithm works using some very simple example?

And also, perhaps you know some software or a code that would transform phrases into their MD5. If yes, please, let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for a detailed explanation of the internal workings of MD5 or do you just want to know how to calculate a hash in some language, given a phrase?

Comment: Hi, Matti!!! I just want to calculate. I am afraid i am not up to understanding all the workings of MD5

Comment: What language are you using? Most languages have built-in support for hashing nowadays. Also, don't worry, I've never taken the time to really read how hashing algorithms work either. I leave that up to the cryptography people. Just remember that MD5 isn't considered safe anymore, it can be cracked reasonably fast using things such as rainbow tables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

Comment: Hi, Matti!!! I am using python and became interested in MD5 because, while trying to find a python code that would log in from Google App Engine to a certain website (like my account on Yahoo or on eBay), one of the answerers here suggested that I send MD5 instead of the plain password. It happened on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571450/using-cookiejar-in-python-to-log-in-to-a-website-from-google-app-engine-whats
Thank You for Rainbow-tables reference to the Wiki - it is very interesting.

Comment: Ah, but you just want to use MD5, not code it! The Python documentation describes how to generate an MD5 hash: http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html

Comment: I am sorry for having not made my point clear enough. Thank You for this link - before I didn't even know that MD5 hash could be generated in Python. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the endians: it's just a way name for a way to encode information.

Let's follow the wikipedia [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm) article. You start with an input message. It can be arbitrarily long: MD5 hashes for 2GB ISO files are routinely created, just like hashes for strings a dozen characters long (e.g. for passwords).

The hash will be contained in registers `a` , `b`, `c` and `d`. These registers are initialized with special values (`h0-h3`).

The algorithm breaks the input into 16 4-byte chunks ("sixteen 32-bit little-endian words") and applies specific logical operations (functions `F`, `G`, `H` and `I`) on parts of the input and the current state of registers `a` , `b`, `c` and `d`. It does this 64 times for each set of 16 4-byte chunks.

When all of the chunks are processed, what remains in `a` , `b`, `c` and `d` is the final hash, the one you might get by invoking `md5sum testfile.txt`.

Update:

If you just want to be able to calculate a hash, implementing it yourself makes no sense because it's been done and tested for probably every significant language out there:

[Python](http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html):

```
import md5
md5.new("Nobody inspects the spammish repetition").digest()
```

SQL ([MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)):

```
SELECT MD5('Nobody inspects the spammish repetition')
```

[Java](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3686):

```
String s="Nobody inspects the spammish repetition";
MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
System.out.println(new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16));
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you, Tomislav, for this answer. I am studying Your answer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Md5 is a hash algorithm: It produces a signature of the input text such that changing any letter in the input will have significant, unpredictable impact on the signature.

For instance:

The md5 signature of the text 'This is a quite short text which looks quite normal' is '2bb1a5a5204aba95c886b3eb598c9d41'

The md5 signature of the same text with an added period, 'This is a quite short text which looks quite normal.' is '870df12558aae47b40bf738290ba8554'

As you see, there signature differs significantly. This property makes md5 suitable as a type of 'fingerprinting': Two books who only differ by one letter have completely different md5s. Futhermore, two md5s are almost never the same for any pair of different books: collisions are extremely rare.

There are numerous implementations of md5, including several online versions ([here is one](http://md5-hash-online.waraxe.us/)). If you want one in a specific language, please specify which.

Comment: WOW!!! disown, thank You very much for this link. I am sorry I forgot to specify the language - I am interested in python.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is horribly broken and has been for years.  Do not use for any purpose if you can possibly help it.  In new applications, use a SHA-2 hash function such as SHA-256.

Comment: Thank You, Paul, for telling me that.